# Is it feasible to use furring strip to create a large frame?

Tags: wood-selection

My first woodworking project. I've completed a large puzzle, dimensions ~ 62" x 42", and I'm interested in creating a "frameless" frame to mount it on the wall. This would involve cutting and securing long, slender cuts (preliminary dimensions 1" x 2") to a 1/4" thick piece of MDF board. The entire process can be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-4nex0K6xFI).

The video uses pine DAR (Dressed All Round, seems to be an Aussie product) secured to a 6mm thick MDF board. The sides of the pine DAR are stained as well. However, I can't seem to find any DAR locally in the US. I've seen that furring strip is cheap and comes cut in dimensions I can easily work with.

1. Is furring strip "structurally" sturdy enough for me to use in this application?
2. Is there a specific name for the "x brace" pattern being used here?

[image]

Comment: Note that most people are not going to visit that video link. You should make sure everything you relevant is in the text of the question. For example, does this construction require some sort of plywood backing? It's unclear to me what the actual construction is.

Comment: Just to confirm what @jdv said, I don't visit YouTube 'blind' vid links as a rule.

Comment: Now to your main query, I think you need to bear in mind how people need unambiguous descriptions to get a clear picture of something. It's so plain to you because you know what it is already, we don't have that advantage. So basically try to do an ELI5, and use no local terms so there's no confusion — DAR for example is not used worldwide, I'd never heard of it before today. It appears to be an antipodean term only, possibly Oz only!

Comment: OK, I had to look up ELI5. Also antipodean....WAIT, was that your intention?  :)

Comment: @Ashlar, sorry no it wasn't LOL In fairness ELI5 is not something everyone knows so maybe that would need to be Googled but I wasn't really thinking of that, just of the character limit in Comments! As for antipodean, if they're from Australia as seems likely I presume they would know that.... living in the Antipodes as they do :-)

Comment: LOL. I had to look up ELI5. Mostly because I and l are the same for my default typeface. Maybe I'll switch to a serif face for browsing!

Comment: @Graphus  Oh the irony, asking for clarity by using unclear ( to me and others apparently ) terms. *An "unambiguous description" of "ELI5" seems to be needed*.

Comment: I guess there are some reddit/voat/phuks users hanging around

Comment: @AlaskaMan, not that it's a defense but I am used to posting various somewheres where the term would be broadly/nearly universally understood. And like I said above to Ashlar, I hit the character limit for Comments and it was the most concise, simplest way of getting the point across. BTW for the record, I just checked and it takes ~1.5 seconds to Google ELI5; top search return spells it out in full, right in the title, so you're done at that point.

Comment: I also had to look up "DAR", which is a TLA with a lot of matches. "DAR" "lumber" was the obvious next step. Luckily, ELI5 isn't as overloaded. Otherwise, we should _generally_ not depend on acronyms being understood. Except for the TLAs we include for irony.

Comment: Ahh yes, TLA. Pretty sure I've flown that on that airline.

Comment: @jdv, we're online. TLAs are part of the landscape whether we like it (or the particular abbreviations) or not. Remember when you didn't know what LOL, WTF, AFAIK, YMMV and, er,  MILF meant? Even the ones you don't adopt for personal use we learn anyway. Anyway, this has gone on too long and will be hived off automatically to Chat if it goes much further so I'm done on this point. Plus it's not helping the OP with his query..... but then he didn't clarify what a frameless frame is so IMHO he's not going to have much luck.

Comment: @Graphus I'm in general agreement with you. I'm just as surprised as you that some TLAs are completely foreign to people, some of whom have been using TLAs within groups since before there was a ubiquitous public internet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use 1x2s if you can find some that are good quality or could rip some from wider boards. The 1x2 furring strips I've seen tend to be inferior quality wood, and more often than not warped, twisted, and bowed.

I don't know of a specific name for that kind of frame construction, but wouldn't be surprised if there was one.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Greg. I evaluated the quality of furring strips yesterday at the lumber store and came to the same conclusion.

For anyone reading this in the future, furring strips are inferior quality and warped. I settled on some 1" x 2" x 8' pine, which worked really well.

Comment: Excellent! Glad to hear it worked out for you.